# TFS - Life Cycle of Product Backlog Item - who changes the state?

Tags: tfs

I'm unclear how the workflow/life cycle of a product backlog item should work - particularly when it comes to who should update the state and when that should happen.

Previously, we used TFS only at the task level, so anything that had to happen, the programmers would submit their code for a task, mark it as "DONE", then as a tester I would either find it was done correctly and mark it as "COMPLETE", or find some error or incomplete implementation and return the status to "TO DO".

Now we've set up an actual structure of Features, PBIs and Bugs, and tasks underneath but I'm still unclear on a few things.

For example:
Project Manager approves PBI and changes the state from NEW to APPROVED. It gets assigned to a sprint and the programmers mark it as COMMITTED, then write a number of tasks underneath. When they finish their tasks, they mark them as DONE.

How should I (the tester) know I can start testing that PBI? Are the programmers supposed to mark the PBI as DONE? And then I test it and if it doesn't pass, I turn it back to COMMITTED? If it passes, do I just leave it as DONE? (I find it confusing how there is a DONE for tasks and bugs that is different from DONE for PBIs).

Or do I look at the task level and see that all the tasks marked as DONE, and change them to CLOSED if they pass my testing or back to TO DO if they don't pass. I then only change the PBI to DONE once all the task testing has passed and all the tasks are marked as CLOSED? (one issue I have is sometimes the task is so programming-specific that I wouldn't know how to verify to change it from DONE to CLOSED).

Answer (score 1):

Technically a "Project Manager" should not be involved in the process at all.

The PBI, as with everything on the backlog, is owned by the Product Owner. The Product Owner is accountable and responsable for the contents, and everyone else's understanding of said contents, of the backlog. However the Product Owner may not physically do anything and can delegate to the team.

So... The Product Owner, and the Development Team, should be the only ones changing states or editing Backlog Items. (caveats exist at scale).

Specifics:

1. As the Development Team is responsible and accountable for getting things to Done then they get to mark it as done when the whole team agrees that they have met the DOD.
2. Anyone can add something to the bottom of the backlog, but only the Scrum Team can change it and move it around.
3. The Product Owner approves the work, bit any member of the Scrum Team can proxy that approval and change the state.
4. **There should not ever be a state after Done.**
5. The whole team (analysts, coders, testers, operations) all work on a PBI in the Committed state. The work item stays committed until it is Done, or abandoned.

Note: You can find out more by reading the Scrum Guide: http://www.scrumguides.org/

Comment: Thanks for your response! In regards to #4, If there isn't supposed to be a state after Done, do you know what the Closed is for in TFS (which you can't change it to until it has been marked as Done)?

Comment: Also, for #5, is there a particular way the programmers are supposed to indicate to the testers that it is ready for them to look at? For example, say they are working on a few tasks within a PBI that is currently shown as Committed. How do the testers know when a task has been addressed by a programmer and is ready to be tested?